# Using a while loop on a dynamic table

Tags: python, selenium, while-loop

I have a dynamic table that displays 5 rows at a time starting from 1 to 5. If you want to look at say row 6 you have to click a next button. Once you click it though the table refreshes the 5 rows and shows you row 6 to 10.

I'm trying to write a script that looks at a particular column in the table. It finds all the ID numbers in each row of that column. Then it looks in a txt file in the same directory. If the ID number / numbers match the numbers in the txt file, a tick box will be clicked, which corresponds to the ID number.

Because of the websites design I have to create a loop that says, "If the ID number is on this page, tick it. If it isn't, click the next button and check on the next page, and so forth."

```
i = 1
while i < 6:
    ID = browser.find_element_by_xpath(before_xpath + str(i) + after_xpath).get_attribute('innerHTML')

    if ID in open('ID_NUMBERS.txt').read():
        tick = browser.find_element_by_xpath(before_tick + str(i) + after_tick)
        tick.click()
        i += 1
        break
    if ID not in open('ID_NUMBERS.txt').read():
        next_page = browser.find_element_by_xpath(skip_page)
        next_page.click()
        time.sleep(20)
        i += 1
        continue
```

I've run this a few times. I actually got the result I was after initially but for some reason it's not working now. At the moment it clicks on the next button 5 times before moving on to the next part of the code. It's skipping the ID number that is in the txt file, when it should be selecting the tick box.

Comment: What seems to be the problem? do you want it to click more pages before moving on? 
in your while loop you are telling it to click five times either a tickbox or a next button

Comment: Just did a quick edit at the bottom of OP. In the txt file there is a ID number, but the script skips past it without ticking the box it's associated with.

Comment: Share html in text format

Comment: There's no issue with the html. When I simulate the click of the next button the table refreshes new results like I said in OP. The rows in xpath reset to 1, even though I'm looking at row 6-10, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem. The only issue I'm having now is that the code is implemented pretty slow (on the case of the time.sleep(#) in the code. I'm now trying to figure out how to remove these and use webdriverwait instead.

```
i = 1

while i < 6:
    time.sleep(4)
    refID = browser.find_element_by_xpath(before_xpath + str(i) + after_xpath).get_attribute('innerHTML')
    if str(refID) in open('ID NUMBERS.txt').read():
        tick = browser.find_element_by_xpath(before_tick + str(i) + after_tick)
        tick.click()
        break
    time.sleep(4)
    i += 1
    time.sleep(4)

    if i == 5:
        refID = browser.find_element_by_xpath(before_xpath + str(i) + after_xpath).get_attribute('innerHTML')
        time.sleep(4)
        if str(refID) in open('ID NUMBERS.txt').read():
            tick = browser.find_element_by_xpath(before_tick + str(i) + after_tick)
            tick.click()
            break
        time.sleep(4)
        i = 1
        next_page = browser.find_element_by_xpath(skip_page)
        next_page.click()
        time.sleep(4)
```